# Calculate FLOPS and IOPS

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to calculate IOPS and FLOPS in a 5 min test, where each runs for 150 seconds. However, I am getting results that are surprising, where the average IOPS on 16 threads is 53986225 with a standard deviation of 1282739 for example. Am I doing something wrong below? Also please point me to any optimizations as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace Threads
{
    class Program
    {
        // Count of operations done per thread
        private static long[] operations;
        // Volatile variable to signal threads to stop
        private static volatile bool stop = false;
        private const float TestTimeInMinutes = 1f;
        private const float SleepInSeconds = 1f;
        // Handles used by threads to signal to it's caller it's done
        private static ManualResetEvent[]  handles;
        
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get optimal number of threads
            var tNum = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            
            // Ask user for thread count
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write($"Please enter number of threads or 0 for default {tNum}: ");
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (int.TryParse(input, out var _tNum))
                {
                    if (_tNum != 0)
                    {
                        tNum = _tNum;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Initialize operations array
            operations = new long[tNum];
            // Initialize handles array
            handles = new  ManualResetEvent[tNum];
            
            // Populate handles
            for (var n = 0; n < tNum; n++)
            {
                handles[n] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            }
            long totalIopS = 0;
            long totalFlopS = 0;
            long IopDev = 0;
            long FlopDev = 0;
            
            // Stopwatch to measure time
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Test {i+1}");
                stopwatch.Restart();
                var iop = MeasureIOP(tNum);
                Console.WriteLine($"IOPS: {iop/30}\nElapsed: {stopwatch.Elapsed:mm\\:ss\\.fff}");
                totalIopS += iop;
                IopDev += StandardDeviation(operations);
                stopwatch.Restart();
                var flop = MeasureFLOP(tNum);
                Console.WriteLine($"FLOPS: {flop/30}\nElapsed: {stopwatch.Elapsed:mm\\:ss\\.fff}");
                totalFlopS += flop;
                FlopDev += StandardDeviation(operations);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Average\nIOPS: {totalIopS/150}\nIOP Standard Deviation: {(int)(IopDev/150)}\nFLOP: {totalFlopS/150}\nFLOP Standard Deviation: {(int)(FlopDev/150)}");
            Console.Write("The Test has ended");
            var finalInput = Console.ReadLine();
            
        }

        private static void FloatOp(object index)
        {
            float floatOp = 0;
            var i = (int) index;
            long op = 0;
            while (!stop)
            {
                floatOp = (floatOp + 0.8f)-0.10f*0.2f;
                op++;
            }

            operations[i] = op;
            // Signal that the thread is done
            handles[i].Set();

        }
        
        private static long MeasureFLOP(int tNum)
        {
            const int numberOfTries = (int) ((TestTimeInMinutes / 2 * 60f) / SleepInSeconds);
            long flop = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfTries; i++)
            {
                stop = false;
                for (var threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < tNum; threadIndex++)
                {
                    // Reset the handle
                    // By resetting the handle, the thread is considered active
                    handles[threadIndex].Reset();
                    // Start a thread
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(FloatOp, threadIndex);
                }
                Thread.Sleep((int)(SleepInSeconds*1000));
                stop = true;
                // Wait for all threads to exit
                WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles);
                // Calculate flops
                flop +=  (int)((operations.Sum()/tNum)/SleepInSeconds);
            }

            return flop / numberOfTries;
        }
        
        private static void IntOp(object index)
        {
            long intop = 0;
            var i = (int) index;
            long op = 0;
            while (!stop)
            {
                intop = intop + 1 - 10 * 2;
                op++;
            }
            operations[i] = op;
            // Signal that the thread is done
            handles[i].Set();
        }
        
        private static long MeasureIOP(int tNum)
        {
            const int numberOfTries = (int) ((TestTimeInMinutes / 2 * 60f) / SleepInSeconds);
            long iop = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfTries; i++)
            {
                stop = false;
                for (var threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < tNum; threadIndex++)
                {
                    // Reset the handle
                    // By resetting the handle, the thread is considered active
                    handles[threadIndex].Reset();
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(IntOp, threadIndex);
                }
                Thread.Sleep((int)(SleepInSeconds*1000));
                stop = true;
                // Wait for all threads to exit
                WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles);
                // Calculate iop
                iop +=  (int)((operations.Sum()/tNum)/SleepInSeconds);

            }
            return iop / numberOfTries;
        }

        private static long StandardDeviation(long[] nums)
        {
            var average = nums.Average();
            var sum = nums.Sum(n => Math.Pow(n - average, 2));
            return (long)Math.Sqrt(sum / nums.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems that with compiler optimization on, the test code is just incrementing op++. How can I go about incrementing the number of operations in this case?

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73875015/accurately-calculating-iops